# ASP.NET Repeater Paging/Sorting

Tags: asp.net, sorting, repeater, paging

So what's the *real* story on how to do this.  All of the examples I find use Default Paging (HOW does anybody find that acceptable???) but I want to use custom paging.  I can't use a GridView because I need more flexibility.  The examples I see all use the PagedDataSource class but I can't find one that uses Custom Paging.  Am I doomed to have to roll my own paging/sorting solution to avoid the bloatware of the other build-in methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple repeater used for paging where a few page numbers are rendered horizontally is pretty easy to code up and re-use.

Comment: That's the route I'm taking.  Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I think most people who need this much custom work will reach for a third-party control toolkit, like Telerik, DevExpress, Infragistics, or ComponentOne.

If you want to do it once you'll probably want to do it again, and therefore it's worthwhile to have a quality, re-usable, generic, tested solution available.

Comment: Any suggestions on which one to use?

Comment: Telerik is good, but it's not free. Telerik has a lot of quite useful controls - at least as long as you don't mind the look-n-feel of Telerik. Personally I think they're little bastards when it comes to skinning/theming them!

Comment: @M. Nilsson: Does the Telerik grid give the developer the flexibility of a Repeater control?  I might not always want my records listen in tabular format.